# Is there a countably infinite Sigma-Algebra? Why?

Tags: stochastic-processes, probability, finance-mathematics

Assume $\,\mathcal{F}$ be a nonempty collection of subsets of $\Omega$. $\,\mathcal{F}$ is called a $\sigma$-Algebra whenever

1. if $A\in\mathcal{F}$ then  $A^c\in\mathcal{F}$, and
2. if $A_1,A_2,...\in\mathcal{F}$ then $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\in\mathcal{F}$

Is there a countably infinite Sigma-Algebra? Why?I want to prove it by definition (without real analysis).

Comment: As not all of the quants here are experts in measure theory I would add from a blog: "there are no σ-algebras that are infinitely countable. This means that any σ-algebra S is either finite (and is therefore just an algebra) or very 'BIG' in cardinality, in the sense that it is uncountable." taken from here: http://www.yaronhadad.com/why-arent-there-infinitely-countable-sigma-algebras/

Comment: @Richard Whatever you want !

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320035/if-s-is-an-infinite-sigma-algebra-on-x-then-s-is-not-countable